# R - Randomize each row in a matrix separately

Tags: r

I am trying to randomize a matrix such that each of the rows in each column are randomized individually so that in the final matrix there is no association between columns. I know that I need to use the `sample()` function and some sort of `for(each column)` loop, but I'm not exactly sure of how to go about doing it. Specifically, I am asking how to write a function that will loop through the columns of a matrix and randomize the rows of each column.

Edit: An example of what I'm trying to achieve

Original matrix:

```
       X1 X2 X3
    1   4  3  6
    2   7  2  4
    3   9  5  1
```

Sample desired output:

```
       X1 X2 X3
    1   7  3  1
    2   4  5  6
    3   9  2  4
```

As you can see, the rows in each column have been randomized separately.

Comment: I'd take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show your desired output - you'll be much more likely to get a good response.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried clarifying what I'm trying to achieve and added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you have a matrix `X`, you can use `apply()` (ideal for matrix)**

```
apply(X, 2, sample)
```

Example:

```
X <- matrix(1:25, 5)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    6   11   16   21
# [2,]    2    7   12   17   22
# [3,]    3    8   13   18   23
# [4,]    4    9   14   19   24
# [5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

Apply the code above gives:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    3   10   11   16   21
# [2,]    5    8   12   20   22
# [3,]    4    9   14   18   24
# [4,]    2    6   15   19   25
# [5,]    1    7   13   17   23
```

I did not set random seed via `set.seed()`, so you will get different result when you run it. But all you need to know is that: the result is random.

**If you have a data frame `X`, you'd better use `sapply()`**

```
sapply(X, sample)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop for each column.

Or you could use:

```
apply(x, 2, function(col) sample(col, replace=F))
```

Answer (score 0):

`colShuffle` and `rowShuffle` in the `Rfast` package are faster than `apply`:

```
library(Rfast)

m <- matrix(1:1e4, 100, 100)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Rfast = colShuffle(m),
  apply = apply(m, 2, sample)
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>   expr    min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval
#>  Rfast  134.2  141.25  165.439  156.9  187.65   278.6   100
#>  apply 1067.7 1166.15 1334.663 1216.9 1309.20 10578.2   100
```